# Python Reduced Echelon Form

Tags: python, arrays, function, matrix

I'm attempting to write a function that produces the reduced echelon form of a matrix. The following is my code.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,1,-1],[1,-2,3],[2,3,1])

def ref(A):    #ref is reduced echelon form

    B = []

    for row in A:

        i = 1

        while i <= 2:

            if A[i][0] != 0:

                j = A[i][0] / A[0][0]

                B.append(row[i] - j*row[0])

            i += 1

    return B


ref(A)
```

When I run the code, my ref(A) turns out to be:

[0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 1.0, 1.0, -3.0]

The second and third rows of ref(A) should be [0, -3, 4] and [0, 0, 13/3] respectively. Neither my values are correct, nor is the answer in the right format (two lists).

I haven't included the first row yet since I'm not sure where and how exactly I'm supposed to.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just some quick notes... 1, you're only iterating over the first column of A. 2, B is a list that is appending numerical values to itself, so it will be a list of numbers, not a list of lists (which is your expected output), 3, i'm surprised you got this code to compile, since the np.array function is expecting a list of lists as an input parameter.

Comment: 1. Since I'm using a while loop at the end of which I'm increasing the value of i by 1 to make it 2, aren't I iterating over the second and the third columns? 2. Interesting; can you offer any tips how to make B append lists and not numerical figures? Thank you, Ouyang.

Comment: on 1, no you're iterating over the rows, and you've hard-coded the columns as the first one: `A[i][0]`. on 2 there's lots of ways.  if you want to use append, just make sure whatever is inside the append function is a list.

Comment: Also, there are libraries that already do this... for python, here's a good starting point: https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/tutorial/matrices.html#rref